# Execute SQL job based on excel or text file message

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, text-files, sql-agent-job

We have a SQL Server Agent job, which we need to run manually based on user/s request.  The request is random and unfortunately, we cannot predict when the users will request it. Also, we have to it in after hours (Plus, it takes over an hour to run).

Anyways, I wanted to see if it was possible to run this job automatically based on a text file we can put on a Share drive.  Users can update this file to say "Run" or "Stop" along with a few parameter values.  I could setup a schedule to run daily and if the status changes to "Run" then the job runs for day/s until the text file is updated to say "Stop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can create and extremely simple small desktop for the user, where they can start Run/ Stop the job (simple C#, connect to database and execute job with the name of the job).
2. You can create a power shell script which will look for a file (text file) and depending on the value will run/stop the job.